# Issue installing dlib python package on 16.04 Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, dlib

I have an issue with installing python packages before deploying my web application . So i'm stuck with the installation of dlib. I had several other issues when i tried installing it but this is the latest one .
I tried installing from the officiel github repo and directly with python pip and with different versions . I  reinstalled python and i installed all the required dependencies but still stuck with the same error .

The server is running  Ubuntu 16.04 (1 GB ram ).

Thanks.

[error that i get when i run dlib installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgOSI.jpg)

Comment: Free up some more RAM maybe?

Comment: This link may helpful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286807/how-can-i-solve-error-of-installation-dlib/58624273?noredirect=1#comment103559129_58624273