# How can I solve Error of installation Dlib?

Tags: python, dlib

How I can install dlib. I tried to install dlib in many way but it's alway error.

Got an error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5e3dfpnu' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/hommy/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-c_rc8wfx/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ik12xcpk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/hommy/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-c_rc8wfx/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hommy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ik12xcpk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_rc8wfx\dlib\
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is available from, https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section

conda instruction are, https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Dlib is support with **python 3.6 to 3.7.0** version s.Try to install the dlib in anaconda prompt by following command.,

step 1:
        **conda create -n env_name python=3.7.0**

step 2:
       **conda activate env_name**

step 3:
       **conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**

-c is stands for channel, conda-forge is one of channels.

you can find all supported packages for conda's in this link https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/